# MySQL child table need to have primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb

I have (all InnoDB) a parent  table `tbl1` with primary key `some_id` and child (referencing) table `tbl2` with `another_id` referencing `tbl1.some_id` as foreign key. `tbl2.another_id` is not the primary key of `tbl2` as this is a **one to many** relationship. Should my child table also have a primary key - maybe for indexing purposes?

The thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857935/having-a-foreign-key-as-the-primary-key-in-a-child-table) almost answered my question but raised more questions about composite keys so I posted another question about that elsewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to have a primary key on `tbl2`.  This will allow you to uniquely identify each row which will be useful for many purposes in the future.  You can read up on the importance of keys with a google search.

Comment: Thanks, just needed to hear it from someone else. Superfluity makes me uncomfortable and paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

When i've done this in the past i have always used an auto incrementing primary key along with a foreign key. You can join on the foreign key and have the required one to many relationship. Are you against having a primary and foreign key in a table? I've always found it useful for quickly identifying rows in the second table.

```
"InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. 
However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced 
columns are listed as the first columns in the same order."
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: No I have nothing against it. My tables always have PKs. I did read the manual and did some research, it's just a lack of experience that made me get a second opinion.